# How to write multi-threaded functions inside a big function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I have a function like this that is working fine:

```
void BigFunction()
{
   void FunctionA(std::shared_ptr<ClassC> c);
}
```

now I want to add another function inside `BigFunction()`

```
void FunctionB(std::shared_ptr<ClassC> c);
```

which also take `std::shared_ptr<ClassC> c` as the input. 
How do I do it correctly and safely so that both `FunctionA()` and `FunctionB()` can run in parallel, which means these two functions don't need to wait for each other and don't interfere with each other? Thanks.

Edit:
Here is the link of the code that I try but failed: https://onlinegdb.com/BJ5_BC0jI

Comment: This question is much, much broader than you realize.

Comment: Have you read **C++ Concurrency In Action** by Anthony Williams?

Comment: Look at [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) or [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to run functions in parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use std::thread or std::future/std::async. For these "task"'s it is better/easier to use std::assync/future since the thread management is done for you.

```
bool func1(int a) {...}
bool func2(int a) {...}

void some_func()
{
    std::future<bool> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, func1, 1);
    std::future<bool> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, func1, 2);

    bool res1 = f1.get(); // Only need this if you care about the result
    bool res2 = f2.get(); // Only need this if you care about the result
}
```

If you don't care about the results you don't need that last two lines. But the `.get()` basically allows you to wait for your functions to finish. There are other options to do this... but its quite a general question...

Threads and lambda's:

```
bool func1(int a) {...}
bool func2(int a) {...}

void some_func()
{
    std::thread t1 = []{ return func1(1); };
    std::thread t2 = []{ return func2(2); };

    // You must do this, otherwise your threads will go out of scope and std::terminate is called!
    if (t1.joinable())
    {
        t1.join()
    }
    if (t2.joinable())
    {
        t2.join()
    }

    // Or instead of joining you can detach. But this is not recommend as you lose the ability to control your thread (left commented out as an example)
    // t1.detach();
    // t2.detach();
}
```

**Update**

Link to your "fixed" code: https://onlinegdb.com/S1hcwRAsL

Here is the code snippet for your convinience (and I am not sure if I have to save the changes! in GDB online!):

```
int main() 
{
  std::shared_ptr<classC> c = std::make_shared<classC>();

  classB* b;
  classA* a;
  std::thread first([&b, &c]{ b->functionB(c); });
  std::thread second([&a, &c]{ a->functionA(c); });

  // synchronize threads:
  first.join();                
  second.join();               

  std::cout << "A and B completed.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such detail explanation. Can you take look at what I did wrong here? Thanks. https://onlinegdb.com/BJ5_BC0jI

Comment: Yes, in your code you can't call `b->func()` directly since it needs an instance of class `B`.  It is much easier to use a lambda here, then inside the square brackets you can capture the "things" you need.... I will try to form an example from your code...

Comment: Updated with a link to your code. You can see that in the lambda (if you are not familiar - these are soooooo useful) I capture references to a/b and c, this means we can pass in the `instance` of objects to the lambda and then use them directly.... hopefully it makes sense?